# Insert new record to table without using portal

Tags: filemaker

How can I insert a new record to another table that is related to the field im currently inputting data into without using a portal? Say that it is a dropdown button that has a value list from another table, but the record Im going to enter is not yet in that table so I am just going to type it. If it is a new record then it should be added to the other table for future use.

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to create a script to do the record addition. You can then use a script trigger on the field or a button to call the script.

For example, let's assume that you have an `Invoices` table and a `Line Items` table, which is linked by this relationship:

```
Invoices::ID -----< LineItems::InvoiceID
```

You could create a script `Make Line Item For Invoice ( InvoiceID )`, and pass the `Invoice::ID` value as a script parameter.

The `Make Line Item For Invoice ( InvoiceID )` might look something like this:

```
New Window [Name: "Create Line Item"]
Go to Layout ["Line Item Layout"]
New Record/Request
Set Field [LineItems::InvoiceID; Get ( ScriptParameter )]
Close Window [Name: "Create Line Item"; Current file]
```

It wouldn't be to hard, once you've got that working, to modify the script to take additional parameters and use them to set multiple fields in the new record.

Comment: Might be a little off topic from my question but since I'm a beginner, how come my Set Field script only has one parameter?

Comment: There are really two parameters there. `LineItems::InvoiceID` is the field in Specify Target Field and `Get ( ScriptParameter )` is the Calculated Result that is basically putting the script parameter you passed to the script into the LineItems::InvoiceID field.

Comment: But when I use the Set Field script I can only set LineItems::InvoiceID or the field and no option for the second one Get(ScriptParameter).

Comment: When you place the Set Field script step you should see two options: `Specify Target Field`, where you select LineItems::Invoice ID and `Calculated Result`, where you specify Get ( ScriptParameter )

Answer (score 0):

You can fake it by making a very small portal (i.e. make it 1x1 pixel),

Then you can use the portal way: give to portal an object name, then when you want to add the record make Go to object [portal name], then Go to portal row with Last set and just put in the value (just make sure you have the Add option checked in the relationship)